# NLog database target

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, database, nlog

I have the following target in nlog.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">

    <extensions>
        <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    </extensions>

    <targets>

    <target name="dbTarget"
      xsi:type="Database"
      connectionString="Server=SERVER;Database=Log;Trusted_Connection=True;"
      commandText="INSERT INTO Logs(LogTime, LogLevel, Message) VALUES (@LogTime, @LogLevel, @Message);">

      <!-- Parameters to log -->
      <parameter name="@LogTime" layout="${longdate}"/>
      <parameter name="@LogLevel" layout="${level}"/>
      <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}"/>

    </target>

    </targets>

<rules>
    <logger name="dbLogger" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dbTarget" />
</rules>

</nlog>
```

In code I get my logger like this.

```
var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetLogger("dbLogger");
```

But it doesn't work. If I add a file rule, the it logs to the file, so my guess is my dbTarget config is wrong.

Comment: logger.Debug("log message"); can you try again?

Comment: [When someone asks a question about a problem with their code, we need to know what is wrong with it. Stating that “it doesn’t work” is not helpful.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: I log messages, they just aren't logged.

Comment: Always good to check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting. Then you will have a better clue what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Did you try remove the last ";" from the commandText:

```
<target name="dbTarget"
  xsi:type="Database"
  connectionString="Server=SERVER;Database=Log;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  commandText="INSERT INTO Logs(LogTime, LogLevel, Message) VALUES (@LogTime, @LogLevel, @Message)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to include a dbProvider attribute in you target tag. Set the dbProvider attribute with the right value which fits to your database. You can find the values here: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Database-target#connection-options

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the connection string:

```
connectionString="Data Source=SERVER;Initial Catalog=Log;Integrated Security=True;" 
dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
```